# jQuery and servlet $.post()

Tags: javascript, jquery, servlets, post

I'll try to explain my problem.

I have a button to create a new row on a table, here is the JavaScript code:

```
$("#btnAgregarCuentasHost").click(function(){

        $.post("AccionesHost.html", { accion:"retornarHosts", indice:"0"}, function(datos) {
                opciones=datos;
            });
        var filas = idDisponibleCuentasHost();
        var tags = '<select id="hostCuentasHost'+filas+'" name="hostCuentasHost'+filas+'" class="NclsAnchoTotal" >'+opciones+'</select>';
        var strNueva_Fila='';
        strNueva_Fila='<tr>'+
        '<input type="hidden" name="idCuentasHost'+filas+'" id="idCuentasHost'+filas+'" value=""/> ' +
        '<td><input type="text" name="cuentaCuentasHost'+filas+'" id="cuentaCuentasHost'+filas+'" value="" class="NclsAnchoTotal" /></td>'+
        '<td><input type="text" name="descripcionCuentasHost'+filas+'" id="descripcionCuentasHost'+filas+'" value="" class="NclsAnchoTotal" /></td>'+
        '<td>'+tags+'</td>'+
        '<td><input type="text" name="cantServiciosCuentasHost'+filas+'" id="cantServiciosCuentasHost'+filas+'" readonly="true" value="" class="" style="background-color:#F7819F;" /></td>'+   
        '<td align="right"><input type="button" id="btnBorrarCuentasHost'+filas+'" name="btnBorrarCuentasHost'+filas+'" value="" class="clsEliminarFilaCuentasHost" /></td>'+
        '<td align="right"><input type="button" value="" name="btnGuardarCuentasHost'+filas+'" id="btnGuardarCuentasHost'+filas+'" class="clsBtnGuardarCuentasHost" /></td>'+
        '</tr>';
        var objTabla=$(this).parents().get(3);  
        $(objTabla).find('tbody').append(strNueva_Fila);
        $("#jQueryTabs1").animate({height: '+=35px',},500)
        $("#jQueryTabs2").animate({height: '+=35px',},500)      

        })
```

and my JAVA method on servlet:

```
private String retornarHosts(Document doc)
{
    String hosts="";
    List<Element> cabeceras = doc.getRootElement().getContent();

    for(Element e : cabeceras)
    {
        hosts+= "<option>"+e.getChild("host").getValue().trim()+"</option>";
    }
    return hosts;
}
```

It works fine, but the big problem is when I press the button for first time, because when i try to use data from servlet response (variable datos) it doesn't work until I press the button twice or add an alert after response like this:

```
    $.post("AccionesHost.html", { accion:"retornarHosts", indice:"0"}, function(datos) {
            opciones=datos;
        });
        **alert("something");**
    var filas = idDisponibleCuentasHost();
```

Sorry for my bad english, I hope you can understand. help pls!!

Comment: FYI, java is completely different from javascript, like apples and lobsters.

Comment: i just put "java" in tags because im using servlets too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean to put all of those lines inside of the function that gets called after the post?  The alert working means you are actually pausing the flow of content and the code below it will not continue until you close the alert.  This typically signals that you have code that is meant to work synchronously while waiting for data that comes asynchronously.

If you are intending to use opciones=datos as the server response in the code that follows then you need it inside of the function also.

Something like this:

```
$("#btnAgregarCuentasHost").click(function(){


    // store a reference to the table we are updating, this happens when a user clicks the button
    var objTabla=$(this).parents().get(3);

    // send a POST request to the server
    $.post("AccionesHost.html", { accion:"retornarHosts", indice:"0"}, function(datos) {
            // all of this happens after the server sends it's response
            opciones=datos;
            var filas = idDisponibleCuentasHost();
            var tags = '<select id="hostCuentasHost'+filas+'" name="hostCuentasHost'+filas+'" class="NclsAnchoTotal" >'+opciones+'</select>';
            var strNueva_Fila='';
            strNueva_Fila='<tr>'+
            '<input type="hidden" name="idCuentasHost'+filas+'" id="idCuentasHost'+filas+'" value=""/> ' +
            '<td><input type="text" name="cuentaCuentasHost'+filas+'" id="cuentaCuentasHost'+filas+'" value="" class="NclsAnchoTotal" /></td>'+
            '<td><input type="text" name="descripcionCuentasHost'+filas+'" id="descripcionCuentasHost'+filas+'" value="" class="NclsAnchoTotal" /></td>'+
            '<td>'+tags+'</td>'+
            '<td><input type="text" name="cantServiciosCuentasHost'+filas+'" id="cantServiciosCuentasHost'+filas+'" readonly="true" value="" class="" style="background-color:#F7819F;" /></td>'+   
            '<td align="right"><input type="button" id="btnBorrarCuentasHost'+filas+'" name="btnBorrarCuentasHost'+filas+'" value="" class="clsEliminarFilaCuentasHost" /></td>'+
            '<td align="right"><input type="button" value="" name="btnGuardarCuentasHost'+filas+'" id="btnGuardarCuentasHost'+filas+'" class="clsBtnGuardarCuentasHost" /></td>'+
            '</tr>';
            // update the new HTML
            $(objTabla).find('tbody').append(strNueva_Fila);
            // show the animations
            $("#jQueryTabs1").animate({height: '+=35px',},500)
            $("#jQueryTabs2").animate({height: '+=35px',},500)  

        });    

    })
```

Comment: I tried it before, but when i did it the only changes that i see in my web is when code run this  :                                                         $("#jQueryTabs1").animate({height: '+=35px',},500)
        $("#jQueryTabs2").animate({height: '+=35px',},500)

Comment: Well, you ultimately need to modify the function that sets opciones=datos to also update the child HTML of select id="hostCuentasHost'+filas+'" So copying/pasting code is probably not the answer anyway.  All your callback is doing right now is updating the value of a global variable, it won't actually update the HTML shown until it runs the click function again (so it's probably one call behind all the time even when its working)

Comment: sorry, i didnt understand what you say, can you do an example pls?